# Add a stroke to a clipped path

Tags: svg, stroke

I'd like to display a stroke around the intersection of two circles.

Here's my code:

```
<clipPath id="clip">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
</clipPath>
<circle cx="150" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" clip-path="url(#clip)" stroke="black" />
```

The stroke of the clipped circle is getting clipped by the `clipPath` as well, but I'd like it to wrap around the intersection of both circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add half the stroke width to the radius of the clipping circle.

For instance, we have circles of radius 50 and stroke width 10.  So we make the clipping circle have a radius of (50 + 5) = 55.

```html
<svg>

    <clipPath id="clip1">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="55" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="5"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip2">
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="55" stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="5"/>
    </clipPath>

    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="10" clip-path="url(#clip1)" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="10" clip-path="url(#clip2)" />
    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have both circles act both as clip paths and as stroked circles.

```
<clipPath id="clip1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" id="circle1" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip2">
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="50" id="circle2" stroke="black" fill="red"/>
</clipPath>

<use xlink:href="#circle2" clip-path="url(#clip1)"/>
<use xlink:href="#circle1" clip-path="url(#clip2)"/>
```

Make sure the second `<use>` element is not filled because it would cover half of the stroke of the first `<use>` element.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work well if the stroke is think.  The joins have notches.